# Why can I have conflicting function prototypes and definitions with the same name?

Tags: c, visual-c++, function-prototypes

I was answering a question and noticed something that seemed odd. The code in question was more complicated, but the observation boils down to the fact that this compiles in MSVC 14.0:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int);

int main()
{
    foo(66);

    getchar();
}

void foo(const char* str, int x)
{
    printf("%s %d\n", str, x);
}
```

This code produces undefined behavior, because the value of `str` in `foo` is `66`, which doesn't point to a valid null-terminated string, so in practice we (most likely) get a segfault.

As stated, I used Visual Studio 2015 - MSVC 14.0 - to compile this. I'm compiling as the code as C. If we try [GCC 5.1](https://ideone.com/Q89wBz), it fails.

At first I thought this was one of the weird thing C allowed in its early days and has been left in it not to break old code (such as implicit function prototypes). But here, we have a prototype AND a definition with the same name, yet they are not compatible. How come this is not rejected by the compiler? C doesn't allow function overloading, so two identifiers with identical names should not be legal.

Why does MSVC not reject this code? Is there an explanation for this behavior? Is this explicitly allowed in one of the standards?

**EDIT:** Because there seems to be much confusion in the comments, I would like to clarify. I *know* how to avoid these kinds of mistakes, I always compile with the maximum warning level and treat warnings as errors; this is not the point here. The question is purely theoretical: I want to know whether this behavior is legal and defined in the C Standard. Because two C compilers behave differently when given the same code, something is wrong.

Comment: I think there is a warning about it... Or even an error with GCC as you said

Comment: @EugeneSh. Plenty, but that doesn't change anything. Invalid code should be rejected.

Comment: Well, If you see the difference between compilers - it is implementation specific..

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you're suggesting that accepting illegal code is something we can call "implementation specific", then I have to disagree. Unless, of course, this behavior is explicitly allowed in one of the standards, but in any case, one of the compilers is doing something wrong.

Comment: I think the compiler is generating the code of `main` based on the prototype. Then it is generating the code for the function implementation. Then there is no problem to link them, but the problem would be run-time when messing with parameters passing. C is not a type-safe language, and function signature is kind of type.

Comment: MSVC v14 gives 2 compiler warnings about the parameter mismatch in the implementation of `foo`. Enable warnings and follow them up.

Comment: @szczurcio This code is not more invalid than accessing an unallocated memory, which is accepted as well.

Comment: Re the Q edit: you should know by now that MSVC does not adhere to the C standard: it goes its own way.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There is a difference between undefined behavior and invalid code, such as `printf)123(`.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the prototype is telling to the compiler: Push one parameter to stack, then jump to the function `foo`. Here it doesn't care of the implementation of `foo`. Then in the implementation of `foo` it is saying, pop *two* parameters from stack. Nothing illegal. Moreover, think what will happen when the implementation is in a different translation unit and compiled distinctly from `main`.. There is no way to the compiler to know about the implementation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What you said would be correct if the definition were in a different translation unit. But in this case, when the compiler reaches the definition of `foo`, it should see that `foo` has already been defined as something else and refuse to go any further; that's what GCC and Clang do.

Comment: @szczurcio In this case no prototype should be required. C was initially designed for single-pass compiler processing, this is why prototypes are needed even in the same file.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `In this case no prototype should be required.` That's just not true. I could have a large source file where a function is defined at the bottom, but needs to be used by something at the beginning, so I create a prototype. This is not at all uncommon.

Comment: This is exactly what I am talking about. They are needed as the file is single pass-compiled. Whenever the compiler is encountering the prototype, it has no way of knowing about it's implementation. And whenever it is encountering the implementation in the end, it just doesn't need to remember the prototype for anything else than this type of checking.

Comment: MSVC's behavior might not be preferable but it's okay as it produces a diagnostic message. The C standard doesn't know about errors and warnings. We also likely can't tell you why the MSVC developers made it a warning instead of an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to C11 (N1570 draft) 6.7/4 *Declarations* (within Constraints section):

> All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or
>   function shall specify compatible types.

The definition serves also as declaration, hence the *language constraint* is violated.

For that, the conforming implementation is obligated to produce a *diagnostic message*, that is in implementation-defined manner, as of 5.1.1.3 *Diagnostics*:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
>   message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
>   preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
>   violation of any syntax rule or constraint (...)

That's all. A diagnostic message may be of any kind, they may even send you a letter, if they like so.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was expecting. Thanks.